# jQuery plug-in not working with Iron Router

Tags: jquery, meteor, iron-router

I'm new to Meteor so I'm trying some code. I'm testing a jQuery plug-in to bring stylish image hover effects and it works when I'm not using Iron router but simple templates - {{> home}} not {{> yield}} - instead.
So, I have a simple masterLayout template:

```
<template name="masterLayout">
  <p> Base Layout!</p>
  <img id="chard" src="chard.png"/>
  {{> yield}}
</template>
```

and a test home page:

```
<template name="home"> 
   <p> HOME page! </p>
   <img id="home" src="image.png"/>
</template>
```

I call the jQuery plug-in on another js file:

```
$('#home, #chard').adipoli({
    'startEffect' : 'normal',
    'hoverEffect' : 'popout'
});
```

I use Iron Router for routing and it works except that the jQuery effect doesn't.
I've tried a few hooks and only achieved the image in the master Layout to respond, not the image on the home page.
So, this should be very simple but, in fact, I'm not being able to make it work...
Can someone help me out, please?

Comment: Did you put the jQuery-code in the rendered-callback of home-template?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you exactly mean? I tried to put an action inside the route in Iron Router and also some onRun hooks...

Comment: Well, I think I understood what you meant, I tried and it seems to work. Thank you! My question now is: why I don't need to put the jQuery-code in the rendered-callback of home-template when I'm not using Iron Router?

Comment: I'm experiencing something very similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38419804/jquery-metis-menu-not-working-with-ironrouter-in-meteor) and am wondering if one of you can help me figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the jquery code is not executed because the template is not in DOM. I dont know how your plugin works but often like with google maps the javascript is attached in the rendered-callback of the template.

```
<template name="home"> 
 <p> HOME page! </p>
 <img id="home" src="image.png"/>
</template>

Template.home.rendered({
  $('#home, #chard').adipoli({
   'startEffect' : 'normal',
   'hoverEffect' : 'popout'
  });
});
```

Comment: That must be it because it solved my problem! Thank you again.