# Jquery (metis-menu) not working with iron:router in meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to implement a sidebar (leveraging the sidebar from [sb-admin-2](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/)When I use the side bar as part of main.html, the toggles work perfectly fine. However, when I implement the same via iron:router and set the sidebar to be persistent, the sidebar loses the toggle/hide functionality. basically, the child level elements are always expanded and I have no means to hide those child level elements. Is there a work around to this?

I've the side bar code here in [pastie](http://pastie.org/10909632) --> This works when in client/main.html

But when I try the same from within a template such as [this](http://pastie.org/10909634) and pass it to iron:router via the below code, the toggle functionality is lost

**router.js:**

```
Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'sidebar'
});
```

I read in this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762266/jquery-plug-in-not-working-with-iron-router) that this has something to do with rendered callback but I'm not sure how I can get it to work here.

Comment: Also having this issue, will report back when I resolve it

Comment: @Andy - I've answered my question. I had got it working the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I resolved it.

`AppLayout`:

```
<template name="Index">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        {{> navigationBar}}
        {{> Sidebar}}
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row breadcrumbPosition">
                {{> breadcrumb}}
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-9 blockablelockable">
                    {{> yield}}
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
</template>
```

**Sidbar.html** is a template with the original sidebar implementation.

**SidebarHelper.js** contains an functino in `onRendered` which initializes the metis menu like so:

```
Template.Sidebar.onRendered( function(){

    $('.metisMenu').metisMenu({
      toggle: true // disable the auto collapse. Default: true.
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I was attempting to the exact same, I'll reference this and report back.